# Create variable that can be defined and accessed in multiple controllers in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, static-variables

I'm creating an app for creating multiple to-do lists. So a user signs in, has multiple lists, and each list contains multiple items. Everything else is working, but I'm struggling to create the items.

My code for creating a new item on a list (this is found in the `items_controller`) is :

```
def create

    @list =
    @new_item = @list.items.build(params[:item])
    if @new_item.save
      flash[:success] = "Item saved!"
    end
    redirect_to root_path
  end
```

And the issue is, I'm not sure how to define what `@list` should be. I have a variable `current_user` (based on the session) for creating a new list, but there is only one user per session and multiple lists per session, so I can't just replicate that method.

Basically, I'm stuck on how to be able to have the item know which list it belongs to (which should be the list whose show page I was just on). In Java I'd have a static variable that I would redefine every time I went to a list, but I tried doing that and it didn't work, and I read that apparently in rails that doesn't work.

Comment: Save your users lists into the data base - even in java web apps using a static variable is not a good idea

Comment: The lists are in the database--the trouble is that even though each list has its own id, the item doesn't know which specific list it belongs to

Comment: How can that be? Doesn't a list has_many items :through something, or habtm?

Comment: It does, but the item hasn't been created yet, so it doesn't belong to anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than storing a variable, you should keep track of the list using url parameters.  You will need to modify your form to include a `list_id` parameter.  Then in the controller when you are creating a list item, do something like:

```
@list = List.find params[:list_id]
@new_item = @list.items.build params[:item]
```

Or if you made your params include an `items[list_id]` parameter, then in Rails it will be accessible in `params[:item][:list_id]` so you should just be able to just do:

```
@new_item = ListItem.create params[:item]
```

If you do it this second way, just be sure to add a validation in the ListItem model to guarantee that `list_id` is present and the list it points to exists.

Comment: That's a good idea--I should keep track of it with url parameters. But really, I think, when I link to a List show page from the main home page, and then while on the list page the list_id will be accessible from params.

Answer (score 1):

The listItem should have a foreign key to the list model, and the list model should have a foreign key to the account. In this way you should be able to traverse the structure easily.

```
class ListItem  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
end

class List <  < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :list_items
end

class Account <  < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists
end
```

Comment: That's exactly how my database is set up. However, in order to create the list item, I need to specify which list it should belong to--and I'm not sure how to specify that (@list) using the foreign key :list_id, since it doesn't belong to a list yet.